# Initialization errors in EJB blocked deployment of the WebLogic application

Tags: java, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, initialization, weblogic

I have a client class from third party jar that needs to be integrated in my WebLogic ear application. A @Startup @Singleton EJB is created to contain and call the initialization of this 3rd party client.
But during the initialization of the 3rd party client, it tried to create some of its own JMS connectors and failed (because no connection in a test environment), then it got stuck there and didn't return a client instance.
As a result, the deployment of my ear application got "Error Timed out waiting for completion: Activate State: STATE_DISTRIBUTED" and cannot complete a normal deployment and have a state Active.

I have tried to make the initialization method asynchronous or the whole singleton EJB asynchronous, but it didn't work out.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ClientStartupBean
{
  ThirdPartyClient client = null;

  public ClientStartupBean()
  {
    //some init
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize()
  {
    try
    {
      Trace.info(TCI, MN, "Start to init 3rd party client");

      client = ThirdPartyClient.getThirdPartyClient(some_init_para_a, init_para_b);

      Trace.info(TCI, MN, "Finished init of 3rd party client");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new EJBException(e);
    }
  }
  //other stuff
}
```

I can see the 'Start to init..' in logs, but not the 'Finished init' in logs the line after initialization of 3rd party client.

What is a proper way to resolve this? Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: What do you mean under "it got stuck there"? Does `getThirdPartyClient()` method throw an exception?

Comment: The ThirdPartyClient.getThirdPartyClient() runs longer than the deployment process then, when the deployment process reaches its timeout the deployment fails. You should work on the ThirdPartyClient.getThirdPartyClient() and introduce a timeout to not stay "stuck" when your initialization fails.

Comment: By saying "got stuck there" I mean the 3rd party client repeats trying to create JMS connection and failed, and get3rdPartyClient() initialization won't return a result.
As a workaround, I have added @Asynchronous for the EJB and called with `sessionContext.getBusinessObject(ThirdPartyClientStartupBean.class).initializeThirdPartyClient()`, then at least singleton EJB can be initialized. But not sure if this can have any undesired effect.
Of course I will try to compalin with 3rd party, but I want to know if there is any mesure to take on my side.